# PEP3101 checker installation

Tags: python, pip, flake8, pep

I want to check `PEP-3101` standard for some codes that I have, for this, I want to install `flake8-pep3101`.

I can not directly install it as it requires PIP upgrade, so I upgrade my PIP from `19.0.3` to `19.1.1`.

After upgrade, I began to install it by running

```
pip install flake8-pep3101
```

I received this error:

> "Collecting flake8-pep3101pip   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flake8-pep3101pip (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for flake8-pep3101pip"

I already have `FLAKE8` installed and Phyton 3.7.

What can I do to solve this problem ? it seems that there is no flake8-pep3101 module for this particular python.

I tried to upgrade FLAKE8 using PIP command "pip install --upgrade FLAKE8" and "pip3 install --upgrade FLAKE8":
It gives me error :

Requirement already up-to-date: FLAKE8 in c:\users\mydir\dev\myvirt\lib\site-packages (3.7.7) Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: entrypoints<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in c:\users\mydir\dev\myvirt\lib\site-packages (from FLAKE8) (0.3) Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pycodestyle<2.6.0,>=2.5.0 in c:\users\mydir\dev\myvirt\lib\site-packages (from FLAKE8) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyflakes<2.2.0,>=2.1.0 in c:\users\mydir\dev\myvirt\lib\site-packages (from FLAKE8) (2.1.1) Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in c:\users\mydir\dev\myvirt\lib\site-packages (from FLAKE8) (0.6.1)

Comment: Try again paying more attention. Make sure you write `pip install flake8-pep3101`, not `pip install flake8-pep3101pip`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you need to update/reinstall `FLAKE8`.

To update `FLAKE8`, use:

```
pip install --upgrade `FLAKE8`
```

To install the latest version of FLAKE8, use:

```
pip install `FLAKE8`
```

To install a specific version of `FLAKE8`, use:

```
pip install FLAKE8==<VERSION>
```

To install a version of `FLAKE8` greater than or equal to one version and less than another, use:

```
pip install FLAKE8>=<LOW>,<HIGH>
```

**NOTE:** if you're using python3 use `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Good luck.

Comment: @padjee If it's appropriate, please edit the code into the question. Comments aren't the place for code as they don't format it.

Comment: I tried using pip3. it doesnt work. I also tried using : pip install FLAKE8-PEP3101>=LOW , pip install FLAKE8>=HIGH . None works.    My PIP is already at 19.1.1. And I have Python 3.7. Or...maybe any alternatives for this flake8-pep3101 module ?

Comment: Unfortunately, none that I'm aware of.